# Events in native library created by "Unmanaged Exports" in C#

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, native

I have written the following code that uses .net4 to run. Since I am using this code in Unity3D that doesn't support .net4 I had to convert it to native code. I am using "[Unmanaged Exports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports)" to export it to a native library.

I can call this function from Unity3D and it works fine.

Now I want to add events to my library and then access these events from another C# code in Unity3D.
My question is: How to create a callback event and register a function in my library to call when it is done? I know how to create an event in a Managed c# code. But note that here I am exporting it to native code and I need to use the event in the native code. So, My library does something as a native code and then I want it to fire a callback function to tell Unity3D that it is done.

Here is my library code:

```
[DllExport("SayText", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static void SayText()
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synth.SetOutputToNull();
            synth.SetOutputToWaveFile("D:\\test3.wav");
            synth.SpeakCompleted += SynthOnSpeakCompleted;
            synth.SpeakAsync("This is a  test text"); 
        });
        task.Start();
    }

    private static void SynthOnSpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs speakCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        var synth = (SpeechSynthesizer)sender;
        synth.SpeakCompleted -= SynthOnSpeakCompleted;
        synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // I want to trigger an event here so the application knows that the file has been created. 
    }
```

And here is how I'm calling this function from Unity3D:

```
[DllImport("mylib", EntryPoint = "SayText")]
public static extern void SayText();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure it will solve your issue but I tried something similar with ios plugin.

Here is the C# side of the plugin:

```
public class CSharpWrapper
{
    // Create delegate type
    public delegate void TestDelegate();
    // Connection with the native side
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void externMethod( TestDelegate onCompletion);

    private static Action callback = null;

    // This is most likely the part you are looking for.
    // That method is marshalled so it will pass its address to the native side
    // When native calls it we can add any code within  
    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(TestDelegate))]
    private static void ManagedTest()
    {
        if(callback != null) { callback(); }
        callback = null;
    }
    #endif

    public static void CallMethod(Action<string> onCompletion)
    {
        callback = onCompletion;
        // Here we pass our own method that is marshalled for native side
        externMethod(ManagedTest);
    }
}
```

Then I have a C section in the .m file.

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef void (*TestCallback)();
    void externMethod(TestCallback testCallback)
    {
        // Here communication with Objective-C code
    }
}
```

Maybe this will get you somewhere near completion. It is also possible to add parameters, just list them as usual and the marshalling attribute will do it all for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But my question is how to define a callback function in c# (Unity) and call it from the library (C# .net 4 exported to native library). I mean how to send a function handle to the library and how to call it. Both in c#, one in unity, one is ms c#. 
Note that my MS c# code is not managed.